# the terminal process terminated when forwarding reference error

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a List. And I used `forwarding reference` to handle both the `lvalue` and `rvalue`. But the program goes wrong when calling `new` operator in `insertAsPrev` function.

```
template <typename T>
class ListNode
{
        friend class List<T>;
    public:
        using pnode = ListNode<T> *;
        ListNode() : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}
        ListNode(T const & e, pnode p=nullptr, pnode n=nullptr) 
            : data(e), prev(p), next(n) {}
        template <typename X>
        ListNode(X && e, pnode p=nullptr, pnode n=nullptr) 
            : data(std::forward<X>(e)), prev(p), next(n) { cout << "ini\n";}
        template <typename X>
        pnode insertAsPrev(X && e);
        template <typename X>
        pnode insertAsNext(X && e);
    private:
        T data;
        pnode prev;
        pnode next;
};

template <typename T>
template <typename X>
ListNode<T> * ListNode<T>::insertAsPrev(X && e)
{
    cout << "insert as prev\n";
    pnode node = new ListNode<T>(std::forward<X>(e), prev, this);
    prev->next = node; prev = node;
    return node;
}

template <typename T>
List<T>::List(initializer_list<T> il)
{
    for (T i : il)
    {
        cout << "initializer list\n" ;
        insertAsLast(i);
    }
}

template <typename T>
template <typename X>
ListNode<T> * List<T>::insertAsLast(X && e)
{
    cout << "as last\n";
    ++_size; return trailer->insertAsPrev(std::forward<X>(e));
}

int main()
{
    List<int> = {1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1};
}
```

#### The output is:

```
initializer list
as last
insert as prev
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 2816
```

#### My question:

It seems that the program stopped in `new` operation.
What causes this problem?

Should I use overload to handle the lvalue and rvalue situation?

Comment: updated@Yunnosch

Comment: What is `List`?

Comment: I recommend to ask only one question. The second one does not seem to be a detail of the first one (which would be OK).

Comment: I forgot to initiate the `header` and `trailer` pointer.And `prev` in `insertAsPrev` is `nullptr`. should I close my question or  just delete it.Sorry for the bothering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `List` constructor doesn't initialize the `trailer` member which you are using in `insertAsLast` which leads to undefined behavior, hence the crash.